# Is Dart's built-in log function automatically tree-shaken on release builds?

Tags: flutter, dart

I think pretty much everyone experienced in Flutter knows that using **print** method is discouraged as it will be shipped to release builds. So I decided to changed **print** to use **log** (from `dart:developer`) hoping it'll be automatically be tree-shaken on release builds since it's a development tools. However, I still wonder till this day if that's true or not. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

No developer.log() doesn't show in release mode. I have tested it. You can also take a look at debugPrint() from flutter/foundation.dart